# can't integrate .htaccess to nginx conf

Tags: nginx, .htaccess

we have .htaccess file including:

```
RewriteEngine On
    # If an existing asset or directory is requested go to it as it is
    RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} -f [OR]
    RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} -d
    RewriteRule ^ - [L]
    # If the requested resource doesn't exist, use index.html   
RewriteRule ^ /index.html
```

after converting it to nginx rules with some site or tools it still isn't working. Can anyone help me?

Comment: Please provide the nginx rules you tried.

Comment: location ~ ^(.*)$ { }

location / {
  rewrite ^(.*)$ /index.html;
}

Comment: Please edit the rules into your question and format it properly.

Comment: Try: `location / { try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html; }`